# react-native-blur in modal

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-blur](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur) to blur a view on react-native but it does not work inside a modal as [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/201) states.

I've tried the idea suggested in the comment by setting a timeout after the imageLoad but it still not blured.

Is there any workaround ? Why does it works outside a modal but not in the modal ? What is the difference between how a modal render in react-native ? That's unfortunately a bug part of my app and I must succeed.

Thanks

EDIT: 
I did it differently. As blurRadius is working for images on android in modals, I use a combinations of images to show exactly what I want of the image.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps useful for other people, I tried the react-native-blur solution but got stuck as well. Eventually this worked just fine for me:

```
<Modal
      animationType={'fade'}
      transparent={true}
      visible={this.state.modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,100,100, 0.5)',
          padding: 20,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.modalContent}
      </View>
</Modal>
```

The remaining part of the code can be found in the documentation of the react native modal: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal